# Use an onClick to change a data-filter?

Tags: html

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLNVbM

```
 <button class="button" onClick= "document.getElementById('demo').dataset('data-filter') = '.blue';">Test</button>

<button id="demo" class="button" data-filter=".orange"><h4>Color</h4></button>
```

I want to change .orange to .blue when clicked. This does not work, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're not accessing the `data-` attribute correctly. Take a read through this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

```js
var filter = document.getElementById('demo').dataset.filter;

//Original data-filter value:
console.log(filter);

//Add a click event handler to the button:
document.querySelector('#changeFilter').addEventListener('click', function() {
  filter = '.blue';
  //Updated data-filter value
  console.log(filter);
});
```

```html
<button id="changeFilter" class="button">Test</button>

<button id="demo" class="button" data-filter=".orange"><h4>Color</h4>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're both incorrectly indexing and calling `HTMLElement.dataset`. Your onclick handler should read `...dataset['filter'] = '.blue'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Q:/ Use an onClick to change a data-filter?
R:/ bla bla bla bla bla bla 30 line :v

```
<button class="button" onClick= " document.getElementById('demo').setAttribute('data-filter','.blue');">Test</button>

<button id="demo" class="button" data-filter=".orange"><h4>Color</h4></button>
```